# Reading open processes/App list in Java?

Tags: java

I was wondering is there any java system class or something that can read open running processes or least say the running applications on the OS.

Like in a windows platform, we have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to view the list. Can we have this info acquired in a java program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Since Java is OS agnostic, and not every OS does process listing the same way, you must execute a command line program like `ps` for *nix or `tasklist` for Windows (after you've determined what OS you're running on, of course) that will list you all processes and then parse them.

Comment: OK, i would appreciate if you could give me some idea regarding the use of comamnd line. E.g i can execute a command through java but how can i read the output of the command in java program. 
  
Like, if i use tasklist, how am i suppose to import the returned output which you see on command line?

Comment: Please check out this link as it will answer this question as well as questions you didn't realize needed asking: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Thankyou so much!!

Comment: You're welcome.  That link refers to probably one of the more important Java tip pages in existence. I've book marked it, and have referred to it many times.

Answer (score 2):

As darioo states, this cannot be done in Java alone, but it certainly can be done by melding Java with other languages such as C in one of many ways including using JNI, JNA, or even via reading one program's output stream into Java via a socket.